# how can i pass the build number of upstream job to downstream

Tags: jenkins

I have 2 freestyle Jenkins jobs say **Job A (upstream)** and **Job B(downstream)**.
I want to send editable email after Job B completes. Also, I want to use the Job Name, Build number and status of Job A in the email content and subject. Can anyone help me with this?

I have tried using the post-build step: "**Trigger Parameterized Build on Other Projects**" and used **Predefined parameters** as :

UPSTREAM_BUILD_NUMBER=$BUILD_ID
UPSTREAM_JOB_NAME=$JOB_NAME

[screenshot for parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVuHi.png)

In Job B, In the email body I am using:
$UPSTREAM_JOB_NAME with Build number- $UPSTREAM_BUILD_NUMBER completed. Please find the test result attached.

But in the email I am getting exact same sentence "$UPSTREAM_JOB_NAME with Build number- $UPSTREAM_BUILD_NUMBER completed. Please find the test result attached." whereas I was expecting something like "JOB A with Build number- 123 completed. Please find the test result attached."

I don't understand if I am following correct steps.

Answer (score 0):

Replace $BUILD_ID by ${BUILD_NUMBER} and $JOB_NAME by ${JOB_NAME}

Example:

UPSTREAM_BUILD_NUMBER=${BUILD_NUMBER},
UPSTREAM_JOB_NAME=${JOB_NAME}